# Drop Down Menu is not working in lesser version than IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

The CSS and HTML code is working fine in Internet Explorer9 .The Drop down is working fine in IE9 and higher.But it is changing its alignment in lower version of IE and drop down disappears.Can anyone guide me how to make it work in lower version of IE or what correction should be done in the codes.

> My HTML Code

```
 <div class="navigation">                
   <ul id="nav" class="drop">
     <li><a href="index.jsp">Home</a></li>
      <li>Upload
         <ul>
         <li><a href="UploadBacklog.jsp">BackLog</a></li>
         <li><a href='MessageUpload.jsp'>Message</a></li>
         <li><a href="upload.jsp">Customer</a></li>
         </ul>
     </li>
     <li>Download Format
        <ul>
           <li><a href="BackLog">BackLog Format</a></li>
           <li><a href='MsgForamt'>Message Format</a></li>
           <li><a href='CusFormat'>Customer Format</a></li>     
        </ul>
     </li>
    <li><a href="Sent_mail.jsp" >Mail</a></li>
     <li>Reports
        <ul>
           <li class="dir"><a href="BackLogReport.jsp">BackLog</a></li>
           <li class="dir"><a href="CustomerSearch.jsp">Customers</a</li>
           <li class="dir"><a href="MessageReport.jsp">Message</a></li>
         </ul>
     </li>
    <li><a href="LogOut.jsp">LogOut</a></li>
   </ul>                
 </div>
```

> My CSS Code

```
 ul#nav {
            margin: 0 0 0 600px;       
        }
        ul.drop a 
          { 
            display:block;color: #fff; 
            font-family: ITC Avant Garde Demi; font-size: 14px; 
            text-decoration: none;
          }
        ul.drop, ul.drop li, ul.drop ul
          { 
            list-style: none; margin: 0; 
            padding: 0; border: 1px solid #000; 
            background: #000; color: #fff;
            font-family: ITC Avant Garde Demi;font-size: 14px; 
          }
        ul.drop 
          { 
            position: relative; z-index: 597; float: left; opacity: 0.7;filter: alpha(opacity=70);
            -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
            background-color: #000;
          }
        ul.drop li
          { 
            float: left; line-height: 1.5em; vertical-align: middle; zoom: 1; padding: 5px 12px;   
          }
        ul.drop li:hover, ul.drop li:hover 
          { 
            position: relative; z-index: 599; 
            cursor: default; background: #0066CC; 
          }
        ul.drop li ul li a:hover
          { 
            position: relative; z-index: 599; 
            cursor: default; background: #0066CC; zoom: 1.15;
          }
        ul.drop ul 
          { 
            visibility: hidden; position: absolute; 
            top: 100%; left: 0; 
            z-index: 598; width: 150px; 
            background: #555; 
            border: 1px solid #000; 
          }
        ul.drop ul li
         {
            float: none; 
         }
        ul.drop ul ul
        { 
            top: -2px; left: 100%; 
        }
        ul.drop li:hover > ul 
        { 
            visibility: visible 
        } 
          ul.drop li ul li
        {
            list-style: none; margin: 0; 
            padding: 6px ; border: 1px solid #000; 
            background: #000; color: #fff;opacity: 1;
            -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
            font-family: ITC Avant Garde Demi;font-size: 14px; 
         }
```

> Image in IE8

[image: Image1]

> Image in IE9

[image: Image in IE9]